# petapoco shared connection

Tags: c#, winforms, petapoco

I am new to .net and this is my first project using c# winforms. for DAL i choose the petapoco.

i go through the sample code of petapoco and i have some basic question where i get confused

my project is multiuser desktop application and performance is priority.

1) shall i use the OpenSharedConnection or not.

2) can we use sharedconnection to do insert / update. plese go through the following answer where sharedconnection use only for select
[Correct way to use PetaPoco in DAL layer (ASP.NET Web Forms VB.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161176/correct-way-to-use-petapoco-in-dal-layer-asp-net-web-forms-vb-net#new-answer) in some example i observed that sharedconnection used for only select and for crud they use

```
var db = new Database("connectionstring");
```

which is the right method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to call `OpenSharedConnection()` explicitly. It will be called for you when you execute your query.

Comment: Thanks, for desktop application, we create single connection and use it in every database call, but here it will create the new connection every time whenever we create the Database object (new Database). can we create the single connection and use it throughout the application. please suggest the right method for desktop application. it will be very helfull if you can send any desktop sample application of petapoco.

Comment: You can pass the connection into the `Database` constructor if you like